# Setting MAC addres in live Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: 13.10, system-installation

I'm trying to install 13.10 on a separate HDD (another HDD is running WinXP) from a USB stick. I have encountered 2 problems.

1. When I try to connect to internet from live Ubuntu (to get help with installation), I get a message from my ISP: "Access denied, if you have changed your network adapter please contact our support". The support advised me to manually set my MAC address in Ubuntu.
   I used "sudo gedit|grep HWaddr" and Ubuntu indeed shows different MAC address than WinXP.
   Question: How do I set MAC address in live Ubuntu 13.10?
2. When I try to proceed with installation without internet connection, the installer gets to the screen where I am supposed to set my location, shows New York (I'm in Poland) and instantly quits.
   Question: Is there a way to install Ubuntu without internet connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way to change mac address on nic is:

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 down
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether  xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

Where xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx represent mac address